# Will barbers in Taiwan shave a beard/a week's growth? If so, how much does it cost?

Tags: price, hygiene, taiwan

Per the question, are there even barbers in Taiwan, or only hair stylists? How much can I expect to pay for a shave, if it is possible to get one?

Answer (score 5):

There's a great review of what sounds like a quality one over on forumosa, titled "[Best. Barbershop. Ever.](https://www.forumosa.com/taiwan/viewtopic.php?t=107159)"

It includes directions to the shop, and points out that they did:

- cut
- trim
- tidying around the ears and neck
- hot towels
- shampoo and massage
- shave of hair around ears

It doesn't say specifically that they'll shave a beard, but unless you're some sort of sasquatch that grows a beard while getting dressed in the morning, you'll likely be fine (even then, they sound professional enough to handle it).

Cost: $400 Taiwanese, or around US$13 (present day exchange rate). A shave is $150 TWD.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is a bit old, but you can show up to the barber I used to use. They did beards with a straight blade. It is perhaps a bit out of the way. It is about a 3-4 minute walk from Tamsui Station at the end of the red line. A hair cut was 400NTD, I'm not sure how much a shave is. I will say that they always did a good job with my hair and have experience cutting foreign hair styles.

2nd Floor, 251新北市淡水區博愛街4號 沙茶羊肉, Taiwan

https://www.google.com/maps/dir//25.1703567,121.4460689/@25.1700314,121.4462459,19z/data=!4m3!4m2!1m0!1m0